# 12v to 5v for a vintage radio project

Tags: power-supply

thanks you in advance for any assistance. I am converting this old AM radio into a bluetooth speaker with an echo dot built in for my 11yo daughter. 
[image: Old Radio]

I removed the inner hardware and tubes. Wow beautiful stuff.

I purchased this amplifier to run the speakers. I set it up using a 12V 1amp power supply I had on hand. The amp with the speakers sounds great.
[link to amplifier](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B071KYTYBM)

[image]

What I need is a reduction in the 12v down to 5v so I can run the echo dot, it has a USB connection.
[image]

I am looking for a plug-and-play option. Would this work?
[LM2596 DC to DC Step](https://www.gearbest.com/development-boards/pp_51010.html?wid=1433363&currency=USD&vip=15877876&gclid=Cj0KCQjw08XeBRC0ARIsAP_gaQB4Yv-iJRW2xRkgYPBgq4na3Cosx6hVU48fDza0poXYtLDV9Qv7FEUaAjGUEALw_wcB#anchorGoodsReviews)

Thanks again for any help, apologize for my ignorance.

Comment: This is a shopping question, which is considered off topic for this site. I will suggest you look at the power supplies section on digikey, though; there are many dc-dc converter modules available.

Comment: Hey Felthry- thanks for your quick reply. I figured my question was too basic for this site. Was just trying to piece together a project without diving too deep. I took a look at digikey DC-DC power supplies as you suggested and wow, yes there are many available. Is there a forum where newbs can ask questions like these? Thanks Dan

Answer (score 2):

It would work, but not with your power supply. The echo dot uses a 5.2V 1.8A supply. With perfect conversion, that is 9.36 Watts from your 12V 1A or 12W power supply.

Your amplifier is a max 100 Watt stereo amp  and the Amazon page recommends a 3A supply. Not sure what speakers you are using, so we can't say how much power you are actually using.

In both cases, you don't have enough power to drive both the echo and the amp from that one supply. Easiest thing is to run a second power supply for the echo dot. The extra cable can be velcroed to the other one to prevent clutter. If not, get a bigger 12V supply and honestly any car 12V to 5V 2A adapter to power the echo dot.

Comment: Thanks Passerby- I did end up increasing my power supply to 12v 3a. I am using the above mentioned voltage regulator. It powers the amp/speakers great. It powers the echo just fine but when I put the two together I get a fair amount of back-round hiss/noise. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: switching regulators can cause noise in audio circuits. Ground loops too. Not sure what's the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Search for "Oki Murata" at Digikey, they have 12V to 5V switching regulator in a little 3-pin thruhole package.